# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, amazon-web-services

This is the tip eclipse shows in its layout editor
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

What does that mean? Here is the error in more detail
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.os.Environment
    at com.amazon.device.ads.DebugProperties.readDebugProperties(DebugProperties.java:78)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.(InternalAdRegistration.java:58)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.(InternalAdRegistration.java:54)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:203)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:183)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.(AdLayout.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)

I have tried to integrate the ads using both code and xml but nothing works?
Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Amazon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.amazon.device.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" >

<com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout  
android:id="@+id/myAdView" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am using amazon-ads-5.1.153.jar from their sdk. Here is my main.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
    appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
    AdLayout adView;
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, appliedtheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdRegistration.setAppKey("AppKey");
    adView = new AdLayout(this);
    adView.loadAd(new AdTargetingOptions());

    AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);
    AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);

    AdTargetingOptions adOptions = new AdTargetingOptions();    
    adView.loadAd(adOptions);
```

Has anyone faced this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may instiate ad in java code as

private static final String APP_KEY = "your app key"; 
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "adsample";

```
AdLayout ad;
ViewGroup adcon;
```

this.adcon = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

```
     AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);
        // For debugging purposes flag all ad requests as tests, but set to false for production builds.
        AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);

        try {
            AdRegistration.setAppKey(APP_KEY);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IllegalArgumentException thrown: " + e.toString());
            return;
        }

        ad = new AdLayout(this,AdSize.SIZE_300x250);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ad.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        ad.loadAd();
        adcon.addView(ad);
```

This will really works